# get all elements with type datetime and add datepicker to them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wanted a quick way of adding the datepicker to all my datetime textboxes

im using razor and it has created my textboxes as below

```
<input type="datetime"... />
```

what jquery function can i use to find these?

ive tried along the lines of

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    this.filter('input:datetime').each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

but i get "doesnt support property filter" im using latest version of jquery

THanks

EDIT: adding mode code

option 1:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime?> ShippedDate { get; set; }
```

option2

```
Public DateTime _ShippedDate = DateTime.Now;
public Nullable<System.DateTime> ShippedDate { 
    get { return _ShippedDate ; }
    set { _ShippedDate = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$('input[type=datetime]').datepicker()` should work for you.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aF8hU/)**

Comment: not sure if this is related, but when I click in a datetime i get JQMIGRATE: jQuery.event.handle is undocumented and deprecated, am i missing an update? Thanks

Comment: You're getting that in the jsFiddle example or your own code?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using and do you have other code that could be related to the message?

Comment: * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1 and /*! jQuery UI - v1.10.3 - 2013-05-03

Comment: Only difference between your setup and the fiddle is UI. When I add migrate to the fiddle i don't get the message.

Comment: sorted, i just had to put it on the right page for the onload, it works fine now! :) THanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make an editor template like this that will make all of your date times in to datepickers.

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToShortDateString(), new {type = "datetime", @class = "datepicker"})
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({});
  });
});
</script>
```

If you do it like this then all of your textboxes tied to a DateTime object will be made in to datepickers automagically.

You just put this in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates and name it DateTime.cshtml

**EDIT 1:**

Here is how you would initialize a date time property so that you can be sure it is not null when passed.  Inside your model you would declare it like this:

```
private DateTime _suppliedDate = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime SuppliedDate
{
  get { return _suppliedDate; }
  set { _suppliedDate = value; }
}
```

In this way the date is initialized and you can still access it via the SuppliedDate property.  If you have any questions about this please let me know.

**EDIT 2:**

I believe some additional Googling has turned up the solution to your problem I think.  In the original editor template you should be able to just change @model DateTime to @model DateTime?

The question mark makes the variable a nullable DateTime rather than a normal DateTime.  If you plan to be able to leave the Date field null then you should ignore the initializer that I posted and just add the question mark.  If you do not want to allow the DateTime to be null then you should use the initializer and do not add the question mark.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: getting erro: the model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Are you using a model to get the data that is entered in to the text boxes?

Comment: yes ITAPP.Models.tblName (using entity framework so each table table name will change)

Comment: Are you creating the text box like this:   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyDateProperty)

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SuppliedDate)

Comment: Ahh ok you need to make sure you initialize your date time properties.  I will edit my original post with how to do that.

Comment: also, just to add that the date fields are null in the DB until added, im guessing this is the issue, do i need to add a condition?

Comment: Added an additional edit.  I have provided a method for nullable DateTime objects if that is what you are using.  You will need to change your Model to use DateTime? instead of DateTime if you decide to go this route.  If you do not want your DateTime's to be null then use the initializer that I provided.

Comment: i dont mind the dates being null, ive got Nullable at the begining of them all, based on what you told me, ive added option 1 and 2 above, the bit in option 2, for datetime.now, was that an example or is thats whats needed?

Comment: That was an example of what to put there.  You just need to initialize it in some way.  But if you want the nulls or need the nulls then you do not need the initialization.  You can just make all of your DateTime objects in to DateTime? objects to allow them to be nullable.